# Are there any studies about whether it is better for the government to tell the truth?

Tags: government

I remember once reading a text about the British government sending spies into the underground stations during the Blitz to survey the opinion of the people. The conclusion being, that no matter how harrowing the truth the people would want the government to be honest to them and tell them the truth rather than living in uncertainty. Sadly I was not able to track this text.

My question being:

Are there any studies conducted on whether it is better for the government to tell the truth no matter how dire the situation(or especially in dire times)?
Any event in history where it turned out to be better for the leaders(Kings, Dictators, Presidents etc.) to be truthful with the people would also be great.

Comment: "Better" implies several value judgement context questions must be answered. Better for whom? Better for what purpose? Better over what timescale? Better in what sense? Better by what metric?